# Get cell of 2D Matrix in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, matrix, google-apps-script

I have this function as a custom function in Google Apps Script being used in a spreadsheet:

```
function MultiplyMatrix(m2, m1) {
    var result = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < m2.length; j++) {
        result[j] = [];
        for(var k = 0; k < m1[0].length; k++) {
            var sum = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
                sum += m1[i][k] * m2[j][i];
            }
            result[j].push(sum);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there a way to get a specific index of the array without getting the whole result matrix input into the spreadsheet, If so what is the syntax?

I have this:

[image]

I want just this:

[image]

Comment: How is this an Excel question? Attaching the wrong technical tag only confuses the issue.

Comment: return result[j][k];

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment, I'll use an answer. Given how your question is formulated, a simple answer can be to change your custom function definition so that it takes two extra parameters, the row index and column index of the result you're interested in; hence your code becomes:

```
function MultiplyMatrix(m2, m1, row, col) {
    var result = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < m2.length; j++) {
        result[j] = [];
        for(var k = 0; k < m1[0].length; k++) {
            var sum = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
                sum += m1[i][k] * m2[j][i];
            }
            result[j].push(sum);
        }
    }
    return result[row][col];
}
```

You can then call your function as `=MultiplyMatrix(A1:B2, C3:D4, 1, 1)` to get the value of the intersection of the second row and second column.

If that is not the answer you expect, I suggest you edit your question, tag it also as google-spreadsheet (javascript custom functions are specific to that), and clarify the requirements. A spreadsheet example could be useful for us all to help.